# How to get cmake's PKG_CHECK_MODULES to find my cairo library in Windows

Tags: c++, pdf, cmake, cairo, openscenegraph

I'm trying to build OpenSceneGraph's pdf plugin on a win32 box.  The plugin is using cmake's PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro to find cairo and poppler libraries.  I don't know how to install these in such a way as to help it find them though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "special" way to install them. Any time you install (a correctly designed) library it also contains a PACKAGENAME.pc file which is copied in a directory where pkg-config can find it.

At least this happens in Linux. I don't know if pkg-config would work like this under win32

Have you also installed **pkg-config** as well as **poppler** and **cairo**?

Comment: It's not clear to me what "installing" pkg-config means on Windows.  That's part of my problem.  I'm not using cygwin for this build, so I have to find a way for cmake to find the libraries, or to find a pkg-config that I install.

Comment: Well the pkg-config page says that it is available for native windows (not cygwin) and there is also a README.win32 in the pkg-config release bundle. Have you looked at this?